# OpenGL VBO doesn't show anything when it is put in a class

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I have an OpenGL project where I wanted to wrap all the objects in classes. I started with the VBO. Before wrapping, the code looked something like this:

```cpp
// includes
int main()
{
    // init OpenGL
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // vertices
    };
    GLint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // more stuff
    // create VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    // more stuff
}
```

This works as intended.
I made a class that looks like this:

```cpp
// vbo.h
#ifndef VBO_H
#define VBO_H

// includes

class VBO
{
public:
    VBO(GLfloat *, GLenum);
    ~VBO();

    void bind();
    void unbind();

    GLuint id;
};

#endif

// vbo.cpp
#include "vbo.h"

VBO::VBO(GLfloat *vertices, GLenum type)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, type);
}

VBO::~VBO()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &id);
}

void VBO::bind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
}

void VBO::unbind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

and changed main to look like this:

```cpp
// includes
#include "vbo.h"

int main()
{
    // init OpenGL
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // vertices
    };
    VBO vbo(vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // more stuff
    // create VAO
    vbo.bind();
    // more stuff
}
```

And now it doesn't render anything. I am using OpenGL version 3.3 core profile, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your class needs proper move constructors. I'm not sure if this is what causes the problem or not though, since so much code was removed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, I added a move constructor (at least I think I did... I don't really know what I'm doing) but it did not work. Should I paste the whole code into the question?

Comment: Not the whole code, no. A [mcve].

Comment: Learning how to write copy/move constructors/assignment operators is essential for writing wrapper classes like this one. Might as well do it now.

Comment: `sizeof(vertices)` returns size of pointer, not the size of data. This is your issue. VBO ctor should take `vertices` as array, then `sizeof` applied on array type returns its size (in your current approach array decays to pointer to its first element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  std::vector &vertices instead of float*

```
VBO::VBO(std::vector<float> &vertices, GLenum type)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), &vertices[0], type);
}
```

Also would be a good idea to create custom Constructor and assignment operator , incase you build multiple copies all of them will share the same VAO and VBO and if one gets deleted all of them will hold invalid VAO's and VBO's